# Check digit calculation improvement or optimization

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a simple check digit calculator that I used in development stage now. 
The check digit depends on the account no and constant multiplier `2187654321`. The account no is in the string format. I need to split it into array of integers. 
Then every single integers need to be multiplied with their multiplier respectively.

Let say the account no is 08060002506. So the process will be `2x0 + 1x8 + 8x0...`

My question is, does anyone could advice if there are more optimize ways to do the calculation? Because I will run the calculation for about thousands of account no.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class CheckDigit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accountNo = "08060002506";
        Integer[] multiplier = new Integer[]{2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        Object[] accountNoArr = convertAccountToIntArray(accountNo);

        int sum = getSum(multiplier, accountNoArr);

        int remainder = getRemainder(sum);
        int checkDigit = 9 - remainder;
        System.out.println("Check digit is = " + checkDigit);
    }

    private static Object[] convertAccountToIntArray(String accountNo) {
        return Arrays.stream(accountNo.split(""))
                .map(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }

    private static int getSum(Integer[] multiplier, Object[] accountNoArr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0, multiplierLength = multiplier.length; i < multiplierLength; i++) {
            Integer numToMultiply = (Integer) accountNoArr[i];
            Integer mul = multiplier[i];
            sum += mul * numToMultiply;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int getRemainder(int sum) {
        return sum % 9;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `int` arrays rather than `Integer` arrays (since you're not using a generic collection). If you use `sum += accountNoArr[i] * multiplier[i];` you wouldn't need two extra variables inside the loop. `convertAccountToIntArray()` should return an int array not an Object array (since that's what the name of the method says it does).

Answer (score 4):

Prefer `String.charAt(int)` and `Character.digit(char, int)` to the `String.split("")` and parsing of each substring (and use an `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String accountNo = "08060002506";
    int[] multiplier = {2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    int sum = getSum(multiplier, accountNo);
    int remainder = getRemainder(sum);
    int checkDigit = 9 - remainder;
    System.out.println("Check digit is = " + checkDigit);
}

private static int getSum(int[] multiplier, String accountNo) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < multiplier.length; i++) {
        int numToMultiply = Character.digit(accountNo.charAt(i), 10);
        sum += multiplier[i] * numToMultiply;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why the use of String.charAt and Character.digit?

Comment: @snso Yes. Creating a lot of little `String`(s) with `String.split` is expensive. Accessing a single primitive character in an immutable `String` is much less expensive. Likewise, parsing a `String` with `Integer.parseInt` when you only care about a single digit is expensive. Using `Character.digit` parses a single character.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a stream approach for the `getSum` because streams already provide the possibility to sum up numbers with `sum()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String accountNo = "08060002506";
    int[] multiplier = {2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    int sum = getSum(multiplier, accountNo);
    int remainder = sum % 9;
    int checkDigit = 9 - remainder;
    System.out.println("Check digit is = " + checkDigit);
  }

private static int getSum(int[] multiplier, String accountNo) {
    return IntStream.range(0, multiplier.length)
        .map(i -> Character.digit(accountNo.charAt(i), 10) * multiplier[i])
        .sum();
}
```

Comment: @Jason Thank you, I was using List before and forgot to clean this up. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize the calculation I suggest to use parallel computing of streams, which is built-in function of stream api.

The problem can be treated as dot product between 2 vectors (the account and the multiplier).

This is the code for getting better run time performance:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CheckDigitCalculationImprovementOrOptimization {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accountNo = "08060002506";
        int[] multiplier = {2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        int[] accountNoArr = StringToIntArray(accountNo);
        int result = dotProduct(multiplier, accountNoArr);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int dotProduct(int[] v1, int[] v2) {
        return IntStream.range(0, v1.length)
                .parallel()
                .map( id -> v2[id] * v1[id])
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);       
    }

    static int[] StringToIntArray(String str) {
        return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\B"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray();
    }
}
```

Another optimization step:
you can prepare the conversion of accounts from string to int array in advance. I recommend to run multiple threads that will execute this task. You should create a list of int arrays, initialized with the accounts size (if this size is not constant, then use the maximum size for all of the arrays). Each thread will be responsible for filling in a fixed number of accounts with the converted string.

After joining all of the tasks from these threads, use the same technique for performing
dot product between the vectors. Each thread will execute dot products between fixed amount of accounts and the given multiplier.

choosing the number of threads is tricky, and depends on the running time of individual tasks. Fine tuning approach can be useful.